# How can I make a simple test to verify that Visual Studio 2015 in Design Mode is executing my code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, designmode

Working on a Visual Studio 2015 Windows Phone 8.1 app (Developing on Windows 10!), how can I make a simple test to verify that Visual Studio in Design Mode is executing my code?

I tried to put

```
Debug.WriteLine("DesignMode executing test");
```

in the constructor of a page, but when I load it in Design Viewer, nothing happens. I think the test I made isn't clever.

Comment: In desing mode, you want print text in output window?

Comment: you can check if it is in design mode or not like here:  if(DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
              { // here design mode}

Comment: I wonder if a negative test will work. That is, if you throw and Exception will the designer show that an exception was thrown.

Comment: @RobSmyth I also tried to throw an Exception into the constructor of a page, but nothing happens and also the designer is showing correctly.

Comment: It is a default constructor - that is, a constructor without parameters? (I do not want my comments to become a 'conversation' so try to contact me direct if I can help)

Comment: @RobSmyth It a default constructor, whithout parameters. How can I contact you? I can't create a conversation.

Answer (score -1):

[Component.DesignMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode(v=vs.110).aspx) can be tested.

Comment: Design mode can be tested to check if in design mode, but I do not think that was the question. The question was how to confirm that the code is being executed in design mode.